# Retrieving the entries in descending order and displaying them

Tags: php, mysql

I have serial number (named as srno in my database) as primary key in my database.It is in auto-increment mode. I also have date column in database. For a particular user (say aamir)I want the user's records to displayed in a descending format i.e latest first.

So far I have done this :

```
<?php 
   $query1 = "SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE id='{$user}'" ;
   $result1=mysql_query($query1,$con);
   if (!($result1) )
   {
      die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
   }
   else
   {
      $values1= mysql_fetch_array($result1);
   }
   mysql_close($con);
?>
```

So I have my entries in values1 . Presently my database looks like this:
[image: Screenshot of database with highlighted fields]

Clearly 11,12 and 13 all have entries of user aamir. I want them to be displayed in descending order of their serial number. As of now when I display them them using values1 just for eg:

```
     <label>

            <span style="font-weight:bold">Symptoms</span>
            <input type="text"  class="input_text"  value="<?php echo "                 {$values1['Symptoms']}";?>"  readonly>
    </label>
```

This shows me symptoms of srno 12 and not 13.I want 13 then 12 then 11 . Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add "order by" in your query, like this-

```
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE id='{$user}' order by srno desc" ;
```

Comment: Thanks @Suresh Kamrushi I am able to retrieve srno 13 ,I would like to know how to display  srno 12 and srno 11 .Just like we surf our history using a back button

Comment: @Mithilesh: just update the query in your php code rest of the things will remain same. it will display all records in descending order.